# Any twitter feed in german with short sentences, proverbs, sayings, quotations?

Tags: resource, online-resource, quotes

I'm searching for twitter channels that would provide me daily/hourly sentences in German.

(I can read the news, I understand the titles, but diving in the full articles is still difficult for me. I want something more shallow, superficial, easy to grasp, with fewer words to search for their meaning.)

It's not difficult to find quotation feeds in English, French and Spanish: they could be about anything Zen, Philosophy, Love, Thinkings...

However I have not managed to find any one in German, because I'm not fluent enough to perform the search.

Do you know of any ?

That would greatly improve my level in German that is constantly dropping since I don't practice it daily for too long now. Inside my Tweet List, it would be the perfect place, since I peek at it several times a day.

Comment: I searched for zitate, zen, meinung. Others I don't remeber of. Not sure I tried proverb. Doing it right now.

Comment: With "Zen Sprichtwort" it is a little better.

Comment: "Sprichwort" nicht "Sprichtwort"

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using twitter as a source for learning german (nor any other language), because people tend to not write complete sentences there. Or they use a lot of stupid abbreviations, incorrect grammar or spelling.

Comment: Following German newspapers might be an idea, e.g. https://twitter.com/SZ_Wissen

Comment: @Iris thx for this really nice suggestion. This newspaper does not flood too much.

Comment: @PMF yep, but German people do read them, don't they ? I want to be immersed, softly, and continously.

Comment: @StephaneRolland: Yea, I suppose they do. <rant mode>Different studies do show that the general reading and writing capabilities especially of young people didn't really improve in the times of facebook and twitter. Despite the fact that these at least have them write _something_. </rant mode>

Comment: I can also recommend the Postillion news ticker. The content is mostly satire and word play, so you will have your share of fun and can be proud of your language skills if you figure out the pun :) http://feeds.feedburner.com/blogspot/rkEL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don´t have twitter, but I think you can search for something like:

1. https://twitter.com/sinnsturm?lang=de (there you get some posts)
2. https://twitter.com/chatvgn?lang=de (funny german sms conversations)
3. https://twitter.com/dudenverlag?lang=de (the pure german language)
4. https://twitter.com/landderideen?lang=de (some stuff)

I hope it will help you ;)

Answer (score 1):

Not a twitter feed. But a long list: [https://de.wikiquote.org/wiki/Deutsche_Sprichwörter](https://de.wikiquote.org/wiki/Deutsche_Sprichw%C3%B6rter)